# How to split out string by symbols using regex?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-split

I have input strings like this

> "CC", 5, "B7C15", "B4C8"

I split out this strings via `preg_split` method.
But when input string `$str = 'CC';`
method doesn't work.
My the code:

```
preg_split('/(\\d+)/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

I get the output result:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "B"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "7"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "C"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "15"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "5"
}
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "B"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "C"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "8"
}
```

Instead of the follow result as:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "CC"
}
```

I need to get the follow result as:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "C"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "C"
}
```

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Why don't  you use `preg_match_all` instead?

Comment: Look for existing CSV-parsing tools rather than rolling your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you need any non-digit character sequence split into one char elements, you only need to add `(\D)` (a single non-digit char group) as alternative to your regex:

```
preg_split('/(\\d+)|(\D)/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/zFHybU/1

Comment: Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 2):

A better Approach would be to use:

```
preg_match_all( '/(\d+)|([a-z])/i', $string, $matches );

print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

The file format you're looking at is called CSV, and has many gotchas in parsing.  Rather than writing your own parser with a regex, use existing tools.

If you're reading these from a file, use the [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) function that is built in to PHP.